# expiresByType exception for one folder?

Tags: .htaccess

I'm using the following line in my htaccess to set the expiration of my png files:

```
  ExpiresByType image/png                 "access plus 1 month"
```

However, i need the png files in one exact folder to expire instantly. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it should work if you put it in .htaccess file in that folder. Do not forget to add `ExpiresActive On` directive as well. For example:

Content of **/images/special/.htaccess** :

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
```